# OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied when updating setuptools

Tags: python, homebrew, setuptools

I'm trying to update setuptools using homebrew but I keep getting an error that says:

```
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools-1.1.3-py2.7.egg'
```

How do I allow my computer to make changes to that file so I can update setuptools?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I figured out how to fix it! I looked up the name of that file `setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg` and I found a python [page on it](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools/0.6c11) that says

> NOTE: Regardless of what sort of Python you're using, if you've previously installed older versions of setuptools, please delete all setuptools*.egg and setuptools.pth files from your system's site-packages directory (and any other sys.path directories) FIRST.

So I deleted `setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg` and `setuptools.pth` in `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/` then I went into terminal and typed in `pip install --upgrade setuptools` and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Open Finder and select Go - Go To Folder. Then hit Command-I, and at the bottom under Sharing and Permissions, add yourself with Read and Write Access. This should solve it.

Comment: Thank you for your response, however, I tried adding administrators, my user, and then making all included users able to read and write to the file and it didn't work. It turns out that I had to delete that file altogether along with another one in order to make it work.